# cocoa is file in Package?

Tags: file, cocoa, package

I am looking for a method like isFileContainedInPackage.

I don't see anything like this. What is the best way to determine if a file's path puts that file within a Package/Bundle?

I see isFilePackageAtPath: as part of NSWorkspace but really don't want to have to check every folder above every file.

Comment: Why not? Remove last path component  (while any) and check with NSWorkspace seems like a perfectly valid way. If you need to check A LOT of files, you could optimize and only check paths that have an extension. And if a lookup resulted in a package, you could store that extension in a lookup. But I'd try with simple code first and see if it even neeeds any optimization.

Comment: Does a package have to have an extension? I think the old bundle bit might allow a package without an extension.

Comment: Strictly speaking it would not require an extension. But a bundle without an extension (which I believe is required to have apps claim the bundle) is likely of little use. But of course I do not know your use case, so this may not be tolerable.